# time based (scheduled) haproxy backend backup setting

Tags: haproxy, failover

I have 2 web servers: `A` and `B` with haproxy before them. I'd like to use `A` as a master and `B` as a backup/failover server.

I'd like to know whether it is possible to have:

- no automatic switch to `B` in case `A` is down during office hours
- automatic switch to `B` in case `A` is down during non office hours

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch configs on schedule.
Make two haproxy configs, one for office hours - without failover, another for failover, and switch them with cron.

Comment: When I switch files I'll need to restart haproxy, is that right? So I may be losing a couple of requests twice per day.

Comment: AFAIK haproxy supports reload. So it finishes current requests, then processes new requests with new configuration.